# What does the % symbol mean in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

i think this % symbol is just comment in prolog.I am not sure about it.Could you tell me if i am right?Example,i have seen this symbol like this

```
%path(X,Y,[X,Y]):-
%next_to(X,Y).
```

there are comments?

Comment: Have you looked at the Prolog documentation?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> In Prolog, a `percentage sign (%)` means that the remaining characters
>   on the line should be ignored. [Source](http://www.ling.helsinki.fi/kit/2003k/ctl272/Bangor/clbook_11.html)

---

> There are two ways of commenting in a program. One method is to place
>   the comments between the special brackets / * (open) and */ (closed).
>   Anything placed between them is not treated by Prolog as part of the
>   program definition. The brackets may be separated by any number of
>   lines. Do remember, however, if using this format to include the
>   closing bracket. The alternative is to use the `percentage sign`, `%`. In
>   this case, everything after the sign to the end of the line is
>   ignored.
>
> ```
> %Prolog ignores everything after this sign
> %but only up to the end of the line.
>
> /* However, Prolog ignores everything after this
> bracket until the closing bracket (which may
> be some lines away). */
> ```
>
> Excerpt from, [An Introduction to Natural Language Processing Through Prolog, Clive Matthews](https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=F4-TDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT89&lpg=PT89&dq=prolog%20percentage%20symbol&source=bl&ots=XWFeUTFkKx&sig=5KgzXvWCpKWhc3nAW9ukyBaUyN4&hl=tr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJ1_-xjrjbAhXmQpoKHW1FDIUQ6AEIYTAG#v=onepage&q&f=false)

I think simple google search should work for you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, these are plain normal comments. 
If you want to learn more about structured comments then there is this http://chiselapp.com/user/ttmrichter/repository/swipldoctut/doc/tip/doc/tutorial.html

Comment: why you get -1?

Comment: plain normal end-of-line comments or plain normal multiline comments? (maybe that was the reason?) I think we're supposed to summarize the link's contents, instead of just including it.

Comment: I didn't downvote this question, but I do know that link-only (or essentially link-only) answers are frowned upon. It's best to explicitly include in the answer some specific points you want to make from the linked reference.

Comment: Just updooted to make it +1 bc your answer actually useful :)